# How to filter NASA MARS2020/Perseverance raw images by altitude and azimuth of mastcam?

Tags: mars, imaging, perseverance, api

This URL allows querying NASA RSS API for Perseverance raw images:

https://mars.nasa.gov/rss/api/?feed=raw_images&category=mars2020&feedtype=json&page=0&num=50&order=sol+asc&search=MCZ_LEFT&condition_2=0:sol:in&extended=sample_type::thumbnail,sample_type::full,product_type::raw

Split:

```
https://mars.nasa.gov/rss/api/?
feed=raw_images&
category=mars2020&
feedtype=json&
page=0&
num=50&
order=sol+asc&    
search=MCZ_LEFT&
condition_2=0:sol:in&
extended=sample_type::thumbnail,sample_type::full,product_type::raw
```

I can't understand the syntax of last line, which should allow filtering by the field contained in "extended" object of the "image" object:

```
"extended": {
    "mastAz":"266.764",
    "mastEl":"28.4972",
    "sclk":"669080939.446"
    "scaleFactor": "1",
    "xyz": "(0.0,0.0,0.0)",
    "subframeRect": "(1,0,1648,1200)",
    "dimension": "(1648,1200)"
},
```

I would like to filter mastAz parameter by an interval; I tried several options without success:

```
extended=mastAz::"250-260"
extended=mastAz::"250,260"
extended=mastAz::"250;260"
extended=mastAz::"250..260"
```